# no implicit conversion of Symbol into String? in rails application in rspec testcase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
  #typhoeus running the request
  Typhoeus::Request.new("#{BASE_URI}",
  method: :post,
  body: lead,
  headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
  verbose: true,
  ssl_verifypeer: false).run
```

the typhoeus is throwing the the above error when i m running the testcase for the request when i remove headers line then Http request is calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (Accept: "application/json") instead i changed into ('Accept' => "application/json") worked well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Typhoeus::Request.new("#{BASE_URI}",
{
  method: :post,
  body: lead,
  headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
  verbose: true,
  ssl_verifypeer: false
}).run
```

Comment: Not working. the problem is my product is working fine but when I run unit test case then the above error is throwing very weird.